# PHP header location wont work after uploading to the server

Tags: php, session, redirect, header

This code works fine when i run it on local host but after i uploaded it to the server the header wont work. I used java script window location method, But the sessions in the redirected page is empty. When i run this it just display the message.

```
function userHandle() {
    global $conn;
    global $email;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO votes (Email) VALUES ('$email')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
        $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
        ob_start();
        header("Location: https://sitename.com/login.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
        ob_start();
        header("Location: https://sitename.com/login.php");
        exit();
    }
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: move ob_start(); to top of the page

Comment: Hopefully you're well aware that if your `$email` variable isn't escaped it means you're vulnerable towards SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

header function dont allow any output before it. So either you remove the echo or you can do that with ob_clean();ob_start()

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove

```
echo "New record created successfully";
```

and

```
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the

```
echo "New record created successfully";
```

after an echo to the output stream, you can't use a header()
simply delete them and look at the man-page of header : php.net/header

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do JavaScript for to do direct page

```
<script>window.location = 'URL'</script>
```

header(""); just work well if your put in top your file

i'm not sure why in localhost run very well and after upload at hosting not working

Comment: When i use java scrip the session is empty in the redirected page

Comment: session never empty after you creating it until your destroy that session, you can add session_start(); in every page you want. before declaration a session and always put your session on the top